# Errors in ORS (OpenRouteService) when calculating distance isochrones, what can I do to prevent this?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, distance, error, isochrone

I've made distance 'isochrones' around charging points for cars with ORS. But the result is puzzeling, the resulted 'isochrones' are in some places larger than 250m.

This pictures shows the error on the map:
[image: https://www.wvigisco.be/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/ErrorDistanceIsochrones.png]

The green polgon shows a regular 250 circular buffer, the blue polygon shows the isochrones made with ORS. At least two places, the 'isochrone' is longer than 250 meters.

Here is a picture of the wizard to make the isochrones:
[image: https://www.wvigisco.be/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/ErrorDistanceIsochrones_setup.png]

Here is a picture of the script that ran to make them, there are errors but I've got a result in the end.
[image: https://www.wvigisco.be/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/ErrorDistanceIsochrones_script.png]

We fixed the errors by hand but I would like to know how I can make sure this doesn't happen again. (Especially for a bigger dataset where correcting by hand is not an option.)

Comment: Not an answer to why this happen but this : https://digital-geography.com/comparing-isochrone-apis-an-insight-into-different-providers/ is a comparaison between different isochrone service result that you may find interesting